# React doesn't render with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, dictionary

I'am trying to render a list of property objects with react unfortunately it just doesn't render the content of the list .

```
import Property from "../Property"
import { Container } from "./StyledComponents"


const PropsList = (props) => {

    const Properties = []

    props.items.map(arrayElement => {
        Properties.push(({key: arrayElement[0], value:arrayElement[1]}));});
    return(
        <Container>
        {
            Properties.map((element,index) => {
                <Property key={index} field={element.key} value={element.value}>. 
            </Property>
            })
        }
    </Container>
)    

} 
export default PropsList
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are not returning nothing from your map.
Remove the curly brackets and try again

```
import Property from "../Property"
import { Container } from "./StyledComponents"


const PropsList = (props) => {

    const Properties = []

    props.items.map(arrayElement => {
        Properties.push(({key: arrayElement[0], value:arrayElement[1]}));});
    return(
        <Container>
        {
            Properties.map((element,index) => 
                <Property key={index} field={element.key} value={element.value}>. 
            </Property>
            )
        }
    </Container>
)    

} 
export default PropsList
```